# Getting a "404 Not Found" error when "Preview Changes" is clicked

Tags: posts, pages

I'm using Wordpress 3.3.1, installed on my local machine. I've gotten everything up and running, and I'm able to add posts and pages through the admin interface, but whenever I try to click the "preview changes" button from either one of my posts or pages, I get a 404 Not Found page instead. The URL appears to be correct, I've even tried copying the permalink and pasting it into the address bar, but it still gives me a 404 page. As far as I can tell the posts and pages are being added correctly, and I can view and edit their contents from the admin interface, just not from the main site itself. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What you have (probably) is an error with your `.htaccess` or your local
server wasn't set up / enabled to support permalinks... Try disabling the
Permalinks in admin settings and it should work great.

In most local host you can enable Permalinks support..
*(its called a rewrite module)*

**Here is the option on my localhost (using WAMP)**

[image]

.
Hope this helps.
Cheers, Sagive

Comment: Or you can do in server's console: `a2enmod rewrite && services apache2 reload` to enable module `mod_rewrite` which is responsible for Permalinks support in WP.

Comment: You can add it to your answer. Your answer is useful and can be accepted as correct answer for this question :) All is for @comjuliox

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I had a friend install this for me, and he told me that he didn't modify anything and it was a fresh install, but when I took a look at the Settings -> Permalinks screen I saw that there was a custom structure defined "/%categories%/", so I set it back to "default" and now it's working again.

Comment: Or you can enable rewrite moudle in your localhost as shown in my answer

Answer (score 0):

My solution was really weird, I had plain text containing the word "Post" without any

tags wrapping it-- it had been added in the "visual editor", and after deleting that word it worked! Must have been interfering with php POST request?